# WebMaping using Flex 3 (GeoServer, PostgreSQL, PostGIS, php)

Tags: php, postgresql, flex3, postgis, geoserver

Any idea of WebMaping (Displaying a GeoSpatial Map) using flex 3. 
I have few vector layers and also a raster layer, and i had already build a Geodatabase using PostGIS. I am using GeoServer as map engine.
  If any one have idea please reply me.

Thans in advance..>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, Geoserver already have an api for serving image tiles, you need an API in flex 3 for mapping, I found [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/interactive_maps.html). But you need to modify this example to use your geoserver server, replace openstreetmaps provider to the [geoserver specifications](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/index.html)

Comment: Any idea about how to change the styles of the point WFS layer.

Comment: bookmark this page, its a sld cookbook, very useful : [http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/index.html](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/index.html) if you don't know how to add/edit/remove a style check this out too: [http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/data/styles.html](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/data/styles.html)

Comment: I am facing problem in styling the WFS layer in the OpenScales [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/styling-the-wfs-point-layer-openscales-1-1-flex-3),     Can you help me from this, Thanks in advance...